# What is the most profitable recurring crop?

Tags: stardew-valley

Since quality fertilizer requires fish to craft, and deluxe speed-gro requires coral, both of which are slow to acquire, it seems to me that an effective way to use them would be in the greenhouse with a recurring crop so that it provides a permanent boost. What is the most profitable recurring crop I could plant? Which fertilizer provides a bigger profit boost?

Comment: Quick tangent: crab pots (especially with the Mariner or Luremaster professions) are a great way to get fish for Quality Fertilizer and Speed-Gro fertilizers do not affect a recurring crop's re-harvesting time, only its initial growth rate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ancient Fruit grows in Spring, Summer, and Fall and each fruit sells for 750g each. It regrows new fruit every 8 days. However, getting your hands on Ancient Fruit will be a bit difficult. You'll need to find it in the Mines or buy some seeds from the traveling gypsy. You can also randomly acquire Ancient Seeds by using the Seed Maker. Once you find an Ancient Seed in the Mines, you have to donate the artifact to the museum to get a plantable seed.

However, if you're looking for something a bit more feasible, the berry crops are usually the most profitable recurring crops in each season (Spring's strawberry, Summer's blueberry, and Fall's cranberry).

After some number-crunching, here some hard data. Hot Peppers and Eggplants are ready for harvest the earliest. This data also assumes that you are purchasing Ancient Seeds for 900g per seed.

- On Day 5, Eggplant is the only one showing a profit of 40g per crop. Hot Pepper breaks even while the other crops are still growing.
- By Day 7, Cranberries have ripened and shoot to the top of the leaderboard with 85g per crop. Even though they cost a whopping 240g per seed, each crop can produce 2 or 3 berries that sell at 130g each.
- Day 10, Eggplants have their second harvest and are leading at 100g profit per crop.
- As soon as Cranberries come into their second harvest, they are by far the most profitable crop available. Blueberries and Strawberries fight for a distant second place.
- By the time a full season (28 days) passes, Cranberries are still the most profitable, although Blueberries have narrowed the gap. Ancient Fruit has its first harvest, although it's still operating a loss considering its seed price (it is, however, third place if you didn't purchase the seeds).
- If you got your Ancient Seeds for free (i.e. from the Seed Maker or through crafting the artifact), they overtake Cranberries by Day 40 in terms of profitability (though they fall back to second when Cranberries ripen again before Day 56). If not, Cranberries are still king, though only ~300g more profitable than Blueberries at this point. Ancient Fruit is still third place.

Thus, I can conclude that Cranberries are, numbers-wise, the *most* profitable recurring crop until two seasons (56 days) have passed.

Comment: Since the question mentioned the greenhouse, which isn't affected by seasons, précising which of these berries is the best seller might be pertinent since the ancient fruit isn't so easy to obtain in large quantities.

Comment: Wine/jelly numbers would be cool too.  Ancient Wine and Ancient Jelly sell really well thanks to the artisan multiplier.  You know.  Don't mind me asking you to do a bunch more work on this already fine answer. :)

Comment: @Tofystedeth Kegs and Preserves Jars would affect all crops equally as they increase sell price based on the base sell value of the crop, regardless of quality. Preserves sell for twice the base value plus 50, whereas Wines sell for thrice the base value. Since fruit has a higher base price, put your fruits (Ancient Fruit, Cranberries, Blueberries, etc.) in Kegs and your vegetables in Preserve Jars (or at least the ones that sell for less than 50g).

Comment: It would change the time till you've made back your seed investment however.  I'm just picking nits at this point though.

Comment: For simplicity's sake, I'm fine with ignoring the time til return on investment (although it's good info to have!) and focusing on what crop has the most gross profit. That's part of the greenhouse specific focus on recurring crops. Taking return on investment into account would be more necessary for a "What is the most profitable crop in general" question.