# How to make money in stardew valley

Tags: stardew-valley

I currently have 100,000 G. I’ve been trying to make enough money for the movie theater (500,000 G) But my money amount is going up so incredibly slow. I feel I should be making money quicker because I have 3 pigs, 3 cows, 2 goats, and 1 sheep in my barn. The pigs make iridium quality truffles because of my profession
In my coop I have 8 chickens, 1 baby dinosaur, 2 void chickens, and 1 rabbit. It’s spring 5th year 8. I like to spend money on important things like seeds. How should I make enough Gold?

Comment: Perhaps look at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301296/which-crops-provide-the-most-daily-profit and/or https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259326/what-is-the-most-profitable-recurring-crop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that animal products aren't really the major cash crops they might seem like. The value per item is huge, but the quantity of items just isn't there.  Field crops are where there money's been at, for me, especially if I get sprinklers going so that I can spend my spare time fishing or caving.

This spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DPAq3AyaXIlqML1KummuMHDS_MV3uH0Z7kXAZXKFsSQ/edit#gid=0

Lays out the profit per day from various crops, including if you're kegging/jarring them.

Generally speaking:

- Spring: Strawberries
- Summer: Blueberries or Starfruit
- Fall: Cranberries and/or Pumpkin
- Winter: Winter forage crop seed.

If you've got the greenhouse you can run starfruit and coffee bean year round in there, or any multi-yield crop like blueberries/tomatoes, etc.

Comment: I’m using the greenhouse for rare seeds, grapes, ancient fruit, and coffee beans. I probably will add a few of those other crops though! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, Rare seeds and ancient fruit are, obviously, megabucks. But seed supply for them can be tricky.

Comment: 53 rare seeds plants growing, 12 ancient fruit plants fully grown.

Comment: You won't have money problems for long.

Comment: Yeah. your probably right.